# Где (на каком уровне) должны находиться перечисления в многоуровневой архитектуре?

Tags: c#, архитектура

Имеется каркас приложения с использованием многоуровневой (Onion) архитектуры. На данный момент структура решения в VisualStudio выглядит так:

```
RootNs (Solution)
├ Domain (Solution Folder)
│   ├ RootNs.Domain.DataModel
│   ├ RootNs.Domain.Interfaces
│   └ RootNs.Domain.Core
├ Services (Solution Folder)
│   ├ RootNs.Services.DomainServices
│   └ RootNs.Services.ApplicationServices
├ Infrastructure (Solution Folder)
│   └ RootNs.Infrastructure
└ Presentation (Solution Folder)
    └ RootNs.Presentation.Wpf
```

Интерфейсы (`RootNs.Domain.Interfaces`) находятся на самом нижнем/внутреннем уровне и по идее не должны ни от чего зависеть.
Но где в этом случае должны определяться перечисления, используемые при определении интерфейсов? Сейчас делаю так:

```cs
// RootNs.Domain.Core
public enum FontFamily
{
  Serif = 0,
  SansSerif = 1,
  Monospace = 2
}

[Flags]
public enum TextDecoration
{
  None = 0,
  Bold = 1,
  Italic = 2,
  Underline = 4
}

// RootNs.Domain.Interfaces
public interface ITextBox
{
  TextDecoration TextDecoration { get; set; }
  FontFamily FontFamily { get; set; }
  // etc.
}

// RootNs.Domain.DataModel
public class TextBox : ITextBox
{
  // interface implementation...
}
```

В приведённом выше примере `TextBox` является частью сущности, которая будет сохранятся в хранилище. Само приложение будет содержать уровни представления для WPF и консоли.
На данный момент ([по совету A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081133/182750)) добавил перечисления и структуры, используемые в интерфейсах и доменной модели, в `RootNs.Domain.Core` и уже `Core` добавил как зависимость в интерфейсы и модель. Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря с чисто практической точки зрения я обычно делаю в проекте Domain папку Models и Enums. И этого вполне хватает для обычных целей.

Если же рассматривать луковые и DDD-based архитектуры, то в них обычно рекомендуется делать проект Domain (абстракции, характерные для вашего приложения) и проект Core (абстракции характерные для предметной области). В этом случае смотрите сами, куда ваши конкретные Enum'ы относятся - специфичные для приложения или специфичные для вашей предметной области.

Я бы так сильно проекты не дробил (сомневаюсь, что вы из каждого проекта будете [отдельный nuget собирать для внешних подрядчиков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1078336/213987)), но если очень хочется -- то лучше назовите ваш проекта как RootNs.Domain.Enums или хотя бы RootNs.Domain.Core, слово Shared как по мне тянет избыточные ассоциации.

Вот пример из моего реального проекта (некоторые [фрагменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923732/213987) описывал ранее):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь большинство enum'ов (типа словаря ролей - мафия, шериф, мирный житель) лежат себе в Domain и нет никакой потребности интерейсы и енамы по отдельным проектам распихивать.

А [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766614/213987) можно посмотреть старые архитектуры, которые я строил на сервисах и репозиториях, тут видно, что все интерфейсы лежат в домене, а реализации -- в DAL/Persistence. Судя по вашему вопросу у вас реализации интерфейсов подключают проекты домена и БД, в таком случае как по мне enum'ы должны лежать там, где нужнее (если в домене не понадобились -- снесите в реализацию, если понадобились - вынесите в домен).

Также часто в DDD проектах я вижу проект Common в который сносят вещи, которые не влезают в чёткие абстракции :)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Можно ли сделать вывод из Вашего ответа, что наличие перечислений и структур на самом нижнем уровне приложения не является "костылём", а наоборот является вполне распространённой практикой?

Comment: @XelaNimed Столько книг перечитал, что не уверен, что мы под низом архитектуры понимаем одно и то же :) Низ для вас -- это инфаструктура, а верх - это домен, так? В целом же я видел, много разных enum'ов в проектах и я видел, чтобы их выделяли в доменном слое, редко, но видел. И постоянно вижу, что на каком слое нужны - туда их и кладут (в основном в домен). Но мне кажется, что тут сильно по потребностям, зависит от конкретных примеров. Сейчас поищу в проектах, может допишу в свой ответ. А вы может приведёте в вопросе конкретный пример enum'а? Тогда бы я более предметно ответил.

Comment: @XelaNimed Подумал ещё пока писал. Я держу домен в одной сборке/проекте, а вы дробите зачем-то на отдельные куски. Не спрашивая зачем, могу дать такой совет: в вашем случае проект с enum'ами должен быть отдельно, модели отдельно, интерфейсы отдельно - и в проекте с реализацией интерфейсов подключайте enum'ы. Как-то так у меня складывается понимание, пока больше нечего добавить. Будет конкретный пример -- приводите в вопросе енум, сущность, интерфейс и реализацию, посмотрю.

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Comment: @XelaNimed Посмотрел, в целом пример понятен. Да, я бы в один проект Domain положил бы и интерфейсы и модели и енумы -- а для вашего случая считаю что правильно будет создать отдельный проект, который включить в Domain.Interfaces (и возможно позже понадобится в Domain подключить). А вообще поделитесь, зачем вам понадобилось дробить так сильно проекты, какой в этом был заложен практический смысл?

Comment: Необходимости в таком дроблении нет и сделал так интуитивно. Вы считаете, что в будущем не может возникнуть необходимости использования интерфейсов отдельной сборкой?

Comment: @XelaNimed Да, я с таким не сталкивался в своей практике, потому так не делал бы. И спросил как раз на случай, вдруг узнаю, для чего такое может делаться ) Сделайте тогда один проект Domain, в котором есть папки Enums, Models и Interfaces. Туда же потом Extensions и Exceptions и что ещё понадобится. Вот посмотри как  сделан домен: https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders.git

Comment: Уже смотрел его. Настораживает то, что там вообще не используются интерфейсы.

Comment: @XelaNimed Там используется MediatR, я тоже стал писать таким образом приложения: надоело писать лишний код в интерфейсах-реализациях, перевёл свои проекты на такой подход. Стало чище, удобнее - рекомендую.